# Wordpress remote uploads folder

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, upload

I'm working on the WordPress site. It's currently on client's server and I want to move to my dev server.

The wp-content/uploads folder is more than 13GB and it's a big problem during and after migration.

What I need to achieve is to set up a redirect rules in .htaccess file that will fetch remote files from uploads folder on their server.

For example if I call:

```
my-domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/image.jpg
```

it should display:

```
their-domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/image.jpg
```

so I wouldn't have to migrate all file in order to make the site work.

Also is there a way in that case to write exception for folder

```
my-domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/
```

so every image that I upload now will be fetched from my domain?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 10):

I figured it out and I'm posting if somebody will need it.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/(.*) http://their-domain.com.com/wp-content/uploads/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```